# Unity C# - How do I fix this code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I copied a code from: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/clean-est-way-to-find-nearest-object-of-many-c.44315/

But this code:

```
Transform GetClosestCube (Transform[] cubes);

    void GetClosestCube()
    {
        {
            Transform bestTarget = null;
            float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
            Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
            foreach(Transform potentialTarget in cubes)
            {
                Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.position - currentPosition;
                float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
                if(dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr)
                {
                    closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
                    bestTarget = potentialTarget;
                }
            }

            return bestTarget;
        }
    }
```

It gives the error:

> Assets/Player.cs(29,12): error CS0501:
>   `Player.GetClosestCube(Transform[])' must have a body because it is
>   not marked abstract, extern, or partial

And if I use the code exactly how it was in the thread:

```
void GetClosestCube()
    {
        {
            Transform GetClosestCube (Transform[] cubes)
            {
            Transform bestTarget = null;
            float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
            Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
            foreach(Transform potentialTarget in cubes)
            {
                Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.position - currentPosition;
                float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
                if(dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr)
                {
                    closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
                    bestTarget = potentialTarget;
                }
            }

            return bestTarget;
        }
        }
    }
```

> Error: Assets/Player.cs(34,28): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `(',
>   expecting`,', `;', or`='

Comment: Why downvotes? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I guess you need to read a C# beginners book before you copy code. The code is not valid C#, it tries to declare a method `Transform GetClosestCube(Transform[] cubes)` _inside another method_ `void GetClosestCube()`. That's not possible (and doesn't make any sense here). You'd rather ask the author of the code for clarification,

Comment: @Jip1912: Code in the link looks different than the code 
which has been pasted in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never programed using the Unity Framework so I probably shouldn't be posting here but oh well.  I agree with Rene this doesn't look like valid C# code.

```
        Transform GetClosestCube (Transform[] cubes)
        {
            Transform bestTarget = null;
            float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
            Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
            foreach (Transform potentialTarget in cubes)
            {
                Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.position - currentPosition;
                float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
                if (dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr)
                {
                    closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
                    bestTarget = potentialTarget;
                }
            }

            return bestTarget;
        }
```

Looks more correct to me.  This method is trying to get the closest Cube. Which means you wouldn't want it to return void (or nothing).  You want your method to return one of the cubes you sent in the array, preferably the closest. That's why it has a return type of Transform (because that's a cube).

I would think you would want this method included in a class that has something to do with the Cubes.

Let's say this was in a class called ReadyPlayerOne (bad class name, good book) and the methods job was to tell you the closest cube to an instance of ReadyPlayerOne your code might look like this.

```
public class ReadyPlayerOne {
    Transform GetClosestCube (Transform[] cubes)
    {
        Transform bestTarget = null;
        float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
        foreach (Transform potentialTarget in cubes)
        {
            Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.position - currentPosition;
            float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
            if (dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr)
            {
                closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
                bestTarget = potentialTarget;
            }
        }

        return bestTarget;
    }
}
```

Then you could new up an instance and call it like so.

```
var playerone = new ReadyPlayerOne();
var closestCube = playerone.GetClosestCube(cubes);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: But I can't make the script in a void?

http://pastebin.com/sJbJvSqf

This gives an error

Comment: you can but you wouldn't structure it like that.

it would be more like this http://pastebin.com/0hCJQKSq

Comment: Then I get: (9,36): error CS0103: The name `cubes' does not exist in the current context

Comment: right remember my code is just an example.  If you want to find the closest cube you have to provide a group (array) of cubes to choose from.  Somehow your code has to have a list/array of cubes that exist.  Then those cubes would be passed in to the GetClosestCube method.  If you don't have a list of cubes you would have to create them first.  If this doesn't work then you might need to throw this code out the window and go at it from a different approach.  if you provided more of you code I might be able to help more but based on what's there, that's the best I can do.

Comment: I have this code now which doesn't give me error, but I don't know how to use it. I also did debug.log(closest) but that didnt give me anything. http://pastebin.com/UH2BunXL

Comment: well if I understand what you are trying to do, you are trying to get the closest cube to the transform object.  Your method FindClosestCube() looks like it returns the cube that is the closest.  But your not referencing it.

  var closestCube = FindClosestCube();

Comment: Thanks that finally works. Also, is there a way to find the closest object only based on Z?

Comment: Not sure, I don't use the Unity framework so I am not sure what Z is.  There is always a way thought :)

Comment: Nvm, this works I think for the Z only: http://pastebin.com/Zj6RjSgd I only had to remove the ''.sqrMagnitude'' at float curDistance = diff(.sqrMagnitude); because it's a float, don't know if that matters

Comment: Btw I meant the Z from positions XYZ

Comment: oh sweet, well done. Sorry I just don't do much game programming so I didn't immediately go to the though of 3-D haha.  Glad you got it working though.